# How can I get revision/commitID in changeSet in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to get the commitID/revision in changeSet in Jenkins. And here is my code:

The commitId I got is null but I can get the revision from the summary under the Changes page when the build finished.

```
def project = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(project_name)
def buildnum = some_number

build =  project.getBuildByNumber(buildnum)

def upstreamBuilds = build.getUpstreamBuilds()

upstreamBuilds.each() { key, value ->
  def prj = key;
  def num = value;
  build = prj.getBuildByNumber(num);
}

def changeSet = build.changeSet
if(changeSet != null) {
  def hadChanges = false
  changeSet.each() { cs ->
    hadChanges = true
    println(cs.author)
    println(cs.commitId)
    println(cs.msgAnnotated)
  }
}
```

How can I get the correct commitId from changeSet of the build?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-

To me it looks like you are missing one loop. You have to iterate over the entries in a changeLog (`cs.items` -> would mean an extra loop in your `.each` section).

Comment: @fishi thx for your answer~ I figured out that when I changed commitId to revision, the problem is fixed~ Thx anyway for your help~